# Does Becca Mansell know about Hutch's history?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, nobody

In one of the early scenes in [Nobody](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7888964/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1), Becca Mansell, Hutch's wife, is seen tending his wounds from the fight on the bus using something like superglue to close the knife wound (this is a military technique in battlefield medicine). During their conversation Hutch says something like "just like the old days" and her behaviour seems to imply she is not surprised about his violent tendencies and may have helped him in the past.

But later in the movie, when the family home is attacked by the Russians and she is taking the children to safety, she seems more confused and he has to promise to tell her the full story after the situation is resolved. She would, I assume, have been less in need of an explanation if she fully understood his past.

Does Becca know about his past and the work he did as an 'auditor'?

Answer (score 5):

In an [interview with Connie Nielsen](https://www.upi.com/Entertainment_News/Movies/2021/04/16/Connie-Nielsen-Nobody-sequel-interview/2001618336841/) (Becca Mansell), talking about a sequel, she makes several very enlightening remarks:

> Hutch proves quite equipped to handle himself in hand-to-hand combat with criminals, thanks to his military training. Nielsen said Hutch's wife, Becca, has some secrets that Nobody didn't reveal.
>
> Hutch told his family he was an auditor in the military, and they assumed that meant he had a desk job. After he springs into action, Hutch reveals "auditor" is code for a secret division of assassins. Nielsen suggested Becca might have been complicit in keeping Hutch's secret from their three children.
>
> "We don't really know if she knew," Nielsen said. "I don't think that's a given."

Here she admits that the wife, Becca, may not have known everything about her husband's past, however,

> The 55-year-old Nielsen said she and 58-year-old Odenkirk spent extra time taking photographs to serve as the Mansell family history. Nielsen said fans could find clues about more of the backstory in the photos they took.

So, get a copy of the movie and do a frame by frame look at all the family photos you can see (I have not yet done so.)

> Nielsen, who also plays the Amazon warrior Hyppolyta in the Wonder Woman films, hopes she can join in the action with a Nobody sequel.
>
> "I would think that that would be essential," Nielsen said.

Understandably, Nielsen hopes for more involvement in the physicality of a sequel. More involvement = more screen time.

> In the current film, however, Nielsen said Becca's primary goal is to keep her children safe. While Hutch is fighting bad guys, Becca gets the kids out of the house.
>
> "There's danger happening and the most important thing in that moment is for the children to get out of there," Nielsen said. "That's her job."
>
> In order to finish his action-packed conflict with the gangsters, Hutch asks Becca to look the other way. Nielsen said Becca's willingness to go along with Hutch's plan leaves her room to explore in a sequel.
>
> "There's a lot we have left unspoken just because there's so much we don't know about Becca yet," Nielsen said. "In that moment, I think a lot of women will go, 'This ain't over, but we'll let this one stay on the table for a little longer.'"

I, for one, kind of expect the second film to fill us in with more of *both* character's pasts. It may well be that they both are ex-military. After all, Ms. Neilsen's filmography also contains Basic (2003). Hmm, wouldn't it be special if they were both in the same universe (Basic and Nobody).

Comment: Just speculation on my part, but it seemed to me that she may have also been an agent of some type, or at least something with similar training. After all, she took the violence in stride and wasn't all that worried about Hutch handling it. I got the impression her confusion was more directed at the specific situation, given that they were both supposed to be retired from that sort of thing.

Answer (score 2):

Becca did cure some of his wounds with instant glue. Noone without proper training/background does this.

Becca was told 'not to call 911' and than saw 8 dead masked assasins after a firefight - and only went into the car and left. Noone without background knowledge does this.

She knew and most likely she didnt only knew, she was also a part of it in the past.